# Refresh html page using c# script

Tags: c#

I have a HTML page in my project location and I am trying to populate values from my c# script to the place holder in HTML page. But every first time when i was running the script values got populated with correct details, but in the second run when i am changing my values like my name salary then HTML page doesn't reflect this new value and old data got appeared. Please suggest

Comment: Can you post some code you have been tried?

Comment: are you afraid that if we see your code we might steal it?

Comment: If you update values using a callback, then it doesn't update the view state. Once you do a post back, View State values overwrite the values you got through your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really explain much, in particular which technology your utilizing.  It appears as if you lack an understanding of:

- View State

Viable information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).  In an *Web-Form* application, you'll not only need to account for persistence of the *View State*, but the *Page Life Cycle* as well.  It will play an important role in understanding the fundamentals.

You stated the following:

> The first time the page loads the data exist, when I update the data
>   the old data exist rather than the new data.

Your issue could stem from either a Postback or the control your utilizing.  When a Postback occurs, it means exactly what it states, a Client's interaction with your application transmits data back to the server.

You can remedy such a problem with:

- Update Panel
- `Page.IsPostback`
- `Databind();`
- Ajax

The problem has viable solutions, however until you truly understand the problem we can't specifically help you remedy the issue.  This should point you in the proper direction though.